# How to derive equation from Numpy's polyfit?

Tags: python, numpy

Given an array of x and y values, the following code will calculate a regression curve for these data points.

```
# calculate polynomial
z = np.polyfit(x, y, 5)
f = np.poly1d(z)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

plt.plot(x,y,'o', x_new, y_new)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])
plt.show()
```

How can I use the above to derive the actual equation for this curve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to show the equation, you can use `sympy` to output latex:

```
from sympy import S, symbols, printing
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y=np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)

p = np.polyfit(x, y, 5)
f = np.poly1d(p)

# calculate new x's and y's
x_new = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 50)
y_new = f(x_new)

x = symbols("x")
poly = sum(S("{:6.2f}".format(v))*x**i for i, v in enumerate(p[::-1]))
eq_latex = printing.latex(poly)

plt.plot(x_new, y_new, label="${}$".format(eq_latex))
plt.legend(fontsize="small")
plt.show()
```

the result:

[image]

Comment: I am getting TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'slice'

Answer (score 3):

Construct a simple example:

```
In [94]: x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
In [95]: y=2*x**3-3*x**2+x-1

In [96]: z=np.polyfit(x,y,3)
In [97]: z
Out[97]: array([ 2., -3.,  1., -1.])
```

The `z` coefficients correspond to the [2,-3,1,-1] I used to construct `y`.

```
In [98]: f=np.poly1d(z)
In [99]: f
Out[99]: poly1d([ 2., -3.,  1., -1.])
```

The `str`, or print, string for `f` is a representation of this polynomial equation.  But it's the `z` coeff that defines the equation.

```
In [100]: print(f)
   3     2
2 x - 3 x + 1 x - 1
In [101]: str(f)
Out[101]: '   3     2\n2 x - 3 x + 1 x - 1'
```

What else do you mean by 'actual equation'?

`polyval` will evaluate `f` at a specific set of `x`.  Thus to recreate `y`, use `polyval(f,x)`:

```
In [107]: np.allclose(np.polyval(f,x),y)
Out[107]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to see the equation on your screen to get an impression about the equation, you only need to add the below line:

```
print(f)
```

Here comes more details:

`polyfit` returns a vector of coefficients of the polynomial fit. `poly1d` takes this vector and make a polynomial function out of it.

For example (from Numpy documentation for [poly1d](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.poly1d.html) ):

```
p = np.poly1d([1, 2, 3])
>>> print(np.poly1d(p))
   2
1 x + 2 x + 3
```

Comment: It is important when providing an answer, that you include an explanation so others may learn from your response.  Please edit your response to include a more complete explanation of how your recommended solution resolves this question.

Answer (score 0):

Or, build a string in a loop (this one expects coefficients for increasing order terms, so use `np.flip(np.polyfit())`, and pass the output to the following function.

```
def polyname(poly):
    name = f"$y = {round(poly[0],2)}$"
    for i in range(1, len(poly)):
        if i == 1:
            if poly[i] >= 0:
                name = name + f"$ + {round(poly[i],2)}x$"
            else:
                name = name + f"$ - {abs(round(poly[i],2))}x$"
        else:
            if poly[i] >= 0:
                name = name + f"$ + {round(poly[i],2)}x^{{{i}}}$"
            else:
                name = name + f"$ - {abs(round(poly[i],2))}x^{{{i}}}$"

    return name
```