# How do I convert a np.poly1d object to a string value?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, sympy

I am trying to insert a np.poly1d object as a string in my graph's legend.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#set directory
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx','ChicagoPerThousand')
#set plot
x = df['Fires']
y = df['Thefts']

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.scatter(x, y)
line1 = plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")

#set labels
plt.xlabel('Fires')
plt.ylabel('Thefts')
plt.title('Chicago Fires vs Thefts')
plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(p),))
plt.show()
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

When I run `repr(p)` I get `'poly1d([ 1.313456  , 16.99515723])'` and `str(p)` gives me `' \n1.313 x + 17'`.

How do I convert this to a string I can insert into the legend?

Edit: I've also tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
#set directory
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx','ChicagoPerThousand')
#set plot
x = df['Fires']
y = df['Thefts']

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.scatter(x, y)
line1 = plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")

#set labels
plt.xlabel('Fires')
plt.ylabel('Thefts')
plt.title('Chicago Fires vs Thefts')
plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(print(np.poly1d(p))),))
plt.show()
```

And I get the error

```
runfile('C:/Users/M/Desktop/1.py', wdir='C:/Users/M/Desktop')
  File "C:/Users/M/Desktop/1.py", line 22
    plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(print(np.poly1d(p))),))
                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Furthermore I'd like to have the string be rendered with LaTex. Would I do:

```
plt.legend((line1),('${}$'.format(print(np.poly1d(p))),))
```

?

Comment: What sort of string do you want?

Comment: I'd like to convert the np.poly1d object to something I could render using LaTex and place as the legend, I'm not entirely sure what that would entail however. My apologies for my inexperience.

Comment: What is wrong with the `str()` representation? i.e. ' \n1.313 x + 17' ? You can just remove the new line character if that is what is troubling you?

Comment: If I run ```plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(str(np.poly1d(p))),))``` then I get the error "Cannot convert NaN to integer". It must not like having the x present?

Comment: `p` is already a poly1d type, so `np.poly1d(p)` will likely return some error. This may be what you are seeing there.

Comment: nm, that doesn't seem to throw an error. What is the value of line1 and p when you call this plt.legend()?

Comment: I tried running ```plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(str(p)),))``` and I still get the same ```ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer``` error unfortunately.

Comment: I added an answer with some code, but it differs from yours since you have not provided the excel sheet (so I cannot run your code directly). Try it out and let me know if you still see this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for topher217's help and links to other questions I found the answer in case anyone in the future runs into the same problem.

```
import sympy as sym
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#set directory
df = pd.read_excel('1.xlsx','ChicagoPerThousand')
#set plot
x = df['Fires']
y = df['Thefts']

z = np.polyfit(x, y, 1).round(3)
p = np.poly1d(z)
plt.scatter(x, y)

line1 = plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")

#set labels
plt.xlabel("Fires")
plt.ylabel("Thefts")
plt.title("Chicago Fires vs Thefts")

x = sym.symbols('x')

Eq1 = sym.printing.latex(sym.Poly(reversed(p.coef),x).as_expr())

plt.legend((line1),("${}$".format(Eq1),))

plt.show()
```

The solution was to convert the np.poly1d() object to a sympy polynomial. Then you use the sympy latex output to place inside the legend string. There are probably more elegant solutions to this but this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use LaTex, but I'm getting the poly1d type to convert to string and appear normally using this minimal code example:

```
import numpy as np
# matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(0,10)
p = np.poly1d([1.313, 17])
line1 = plt.plot(x, p(x), "r--")

#set labels
plt.xlabel('Fires')
plt.ylabel('Thefts')
plt.title('Chicago Fires vs Thefts')
plt.legend((line1),('{}'.format(p),))
plt.show()
```

Do you still get the same error using this code? I'll try updating my answer with LaTeX after installing it on this machine.

As for LaTex formatting of polynomials, you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801403/how-to-derive-equation-from-numpys-polyfit) helpful.

Comment: You copy and pasted the above code (i.e. did not edit it nor add things from your previous code using the excel sheet)? If so, please look at your stack trace and find which line the error was thrown.

Comment: Ok I restarted the kernel and your code worked fine! I tried wrapping the brackets with dollar signs but it did not return a latex output. Curiously enough, if I do ```plt.legend((line1),('$e^{x}$,))```, for instance, I get a nice LaTex rendering.

Comment: What is with the single quotation before your $? Is that intentional?

I'm still waiting on the LaTeX install to finish... but that probably has to do with the `/n` character that comes from the poly1d object to string conversion. Let me play around with a few more poly1d objects and if there is a general way to avoid printing these characters.